# CKEditor 4 - Programatically Add Content Templates

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using CKEditor 4 in a Rails 4 project via the `github.com/galetahub/ckeditor` gem. I am trying to programatically add a content template. I have attempted a few things but so far have been unable to get anything working. I also cut out any fancy and attempted the below to no result. What am I missing?

`CKEDITOR.addTemplates("custom", [{ title: "Hello", html: "<h3>Hello World</h3>" }])`

As you can see the popup remains unaltered http://d.pr/i/13tSC

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The word **templates** for templates definition is missing:

```
 CKEDITOR.addTemplates("custom", { templates:[{ title: "Hello", html: "<h3>Hello World</h3>" }] } );
```